# Debugging .NET Core in Ubuntu using VSCode

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I'm working on a team and solution that has 6 people on it, 4 of them are on Windows using Visual Studio 2017 and the other 2 are on Ubuntu using Visual Studio Code. The projects are written using .NET Core.

The solution has two projects in it, one of the projects is a .NET Core (web) project while the other is a .NET Core project that compiles down into a dll and the Web project references it.

Everything works as expected on all operating systemswhen you run `dotnet run` and run the project -- website functions and runs fine.

Debugging, on the other hand, has issues for non-Window machines.  Debugging works fine on Windows with Visual Studio 2017, but when debugging on Ubuntu, it starts the debugger as expected, but then fails to build due to the following error:

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.401/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4176,5): error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "obj/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/logger.dll" to "bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/logger.dll". Access to the path is denied. [/home/developer/data/Solution/logger/logger.csproj]

Build FAILED.
```

We have tried changing permissions on the folders with no luck.

Anyone ever seen or know something to try to get debugger to work in this manner?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest either use a project reference or a nuget reference for the other project not a dll reference. That would be a good start. The error is about failing to copy a file which could be permission related or could be it can't find the file. Linux file system is case sensitive vs windows file system which is not.

Comment: by any chance is `logger.dll` to be created from your own project being referenced?

Comment: Check in System Monitor is any `dotnet` process running. Kill them and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution we came up with is after we clone the git repository, we have to set `chmod 770` on the `obj` and `bin` directories for the project.

After doing this, it worked fine.